# How to find where CSS class is defined?

Tags: html, css

How to find where a CSS class is defined?

So, in my project I have a `custom-css-class` which is applied to some elements. I know it is custom because it has our product name as its prefix (instead of "custom" there is the product name).

The problem is that I can not find that little bastard anywhere in the project. I did `grep -R 'custom-class-name'` in my project's root folder but it did not find any result what so ever (except in the file where it is used, but definition of it, it did not find).

This is strange, because class is obviously defined and does something, because when I remove it from my element, element does not display properly. So, it has to be defined somewhere, but grep did not find anything with that name, and class has our product name in its name, so, it can not be from some third party libraries.

Perhaps it is somehow defined under different name? But I do not see how... Or is dynamically defined at runtime? But if so, that is way past my skill level to find.

But I simply do not see how can it be defined without using its name, since grep found nothing.

Only definition which I could find is in the file where HTML elements are defined, but that definition has a suffix after: `.custom-class-name:after`. I do not know what this "after" part does, but I do know that if I remove its definition from the file, it has no effect what so ever, elements are still displayed properly, and if I remove it from the element, then the element is no longer displayed properly, so it has to be defined somewhere.

I only need to adjust the size of some image. I know that I can override the values defined in that class by defining another class with the property which I want to override defined and applying that class to the element, but, it sounds silly that I have one class which defines something and then another one which changes this value.

I would have to do it, if I am not able to find the definition, but, is there any debugging procedure which I can use to discover where the naughty boy is hidding?

Comment: Maybe you're using sass and the class is defined like this: `&-class-name"`. If you have some sourcemaps, you could locate the file from the dev tool in your browser.

Comment: I do not know about sass, I did not find it, but there are .scss files in the project, if that means something.